# How to check if json object contains <null>?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, ipad

I am getting a **Json** from server by making a network request in my app.I am getting `<null>` value for some keys in **Json** object.My app gets crashed if this type of response is received.Please tell me how can i validate>?

I have tried this but it does not work all time.

```
 if(!(user_post.username==(id)[NSNull null]) )
{

        user_post.username=[dict_user_info objectForKey:@"name"];
         if(user_post.username!=nil)
            {

               ser_post.username=[dict_user_info objectForKey:@"name"];

             }
        else
              {

                user_post.username=@"Username";

              }

}
```

Comment: check `if ([user_post.username length]>=1)`

Comment: use `isEqual` like `if([user_post.username isEqual:[NSNull null]])` also `isKindOfClass` should work too..

Comment: In the first line, I think you mean to be testing `[dict_user_info objectForKey:@"name"]` to see if it's `[NSNull null]`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider testing the value for null so your program won't crash.  Like this:

```
if([dict_user_info objectForKey:@"name"] != [NSNull null])
{
    ser_post.username=[dict_user_info objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Comment: You need to explain why your code example is better than the others. As of now your answer has been automatically flagged as low-quality because of lacking explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Category` of `NSDictionary` and add following method in it, which replaces null value with empty string for each key in dictionary.

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings 
{
    const NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [self mutableCopy];
    const id nul = [NSNull null];
    const NSString *blank = @"";

    for(NSString *key in self) {
        const id object = [self objectForKey:key];
        if(object == nul || object == NULL) {
            //pointer comparison is way faster than -isKindOfClass:
            //since [NSNull null] is a singleton, they'll all point to the same
            //location in memory.
            [replaced setObject:blank
                         forKey:key];
        }
    }

    return [replaced copy];
}
```

**Usage** :
[yourJSONDictionary dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings];

> Read more about Category in iOS [Tutorial 1](http://just-works.blogspot.in/2013/11/subclass-category-and-extensions-in.html) and [Tutorial 2](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/subclassing/)

Answer (score 0):

```
yourJsonObject = [myDic valueforkey@"key"];
if(yourJsonObject != [NSNull null])
{
 //not null
}
** you can also check whether object exist or not 
if(yourJsonObject)
{
//exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've confused your logic.  I am trying to stay true to your code, but let me know if the following is not what you intended:

```
if (dict_user_info[@"name"] != nil && [dict_user_info[@"name"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] == NO) {
    user_post.username = dict_user_info[@"name"];

    if (user_post.username != nil) {
        ser_post.username = user_post.username;
    } else {
        user_post.username = @"Username";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are a couple of methods I wrote for my projects, try them :

```
/*!
 *  @brief  Makes sure the object is not NSNull or NSCFNumber, if YES, converts them to NSString
 *  @discussion Sometimes JSON responses can contain NSNull objects, which does not play well with Obj-C. So when you access a value from a JSON and expect it to be an NSString, pass it through this method just to make sure thats the case.
 *  @param str The object that is supposed to be a string
 *  @return The object cleaned of unacceptable values
 */
+ (NSString *)cleanedJsonString:(id)str
{
  NSString *formattedstr;
  formattedstr = (str == [NSNull null]) ? @"" : str;
  if ([str isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    NSNumber *num = (NSNumber*) str;
    formattedstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",num];
  }
  return formattedstr;
}
/*!
 *  @brief  Makes Sure the object is not NSNull
 *  @param obj Sometimes JSON responses can contain NSNull objects, which does not play well with Obj-C. So when you access a value from a JSON ( NSArray, NSDictionary or NSString), pass it through this method just to make sure thats the case.
 *  @return The object cleaned of unacceptable values
 */
+ (id)cleanedObject:(id)obj
{
  return (obj == [NSNull null]) ? nil : obj;
}
/*!
 *  @brief A JSON cleaning function for NSArray Objects.
 *  @discussion Sometimes JSON responses can contain NSNull objects, which does not play well with Obj-C. So when you access a value from a JSON and expect it to be an NSArray, pass it through this method just to make sure thats the case. This method first checks if the object itself is NSNull. If not, then it traverses the array objects and cleans them too.
 *  @param arr The Objects thats supposed to be an NSArray
 *  @return The NSNull Cleaned object
 */
+ (NSArray *)cleanedJsonArray:(id)arr
{
  if (arr == [NSNull null]) {
    return [[NSArray alloc] init];
  }
  else
  {
    NSMutableArray *arrM = [(NSArray*)arr mutableCopy];
    int i=0;
    for (id __strong orb in arrM)
    {
        if (orb == [NSNull null])
        {
            [arrM removeObjectAtIndex:i];;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return arrM;
  }
}
```

Just pass a `JSON` string, array or object to the appropriate method and the method will clean it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favour and write a method that handles this and put it into an extension. Like

```
- (NSString*)jsonStringForKey:(NSString*)key
{
    id result = self [key];
    if (result == nil || result == [NSNull null]) return nil;
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) return result; 

    NSLog (@"Key %@: Expected string, got %@", key, result);
    return nil;
}
```

You might even add some code that accepts NSNumber* results and turns them into strings, if that is what your server returns (some poster here had the problem that his server returned dress sizes as numbers like 40 or strings like "40-42" which makes something like this useful).

And then your code becomes one readable line

```
user_post.username = [dict_user_info jsonStringForKey:@"name"] ?: @"username";
```

I actually use several slightly different methods depending on whether I expect null, expect no value, expect an empty string or not, which gives me warnings when my assumptions are wrong (but always returns something that doesn't break).

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
if(!(user_post.username == (NSString *)[NSNull null]) )
```

Comment: Casting `[NSNull null]` is both wrong and useless.  It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why ! == instead of good old != ? @Avi: Some cast is needed because the compiler doesn't let you compare NSString* and NSNull*. I'd cast to id (to avoid the impression that the [NSNull null] could ever be an NSString).

Comment: The compiler generates a warning, but it certainly allows it.  I do agree that casting to `id` is better.

Comment: Cast `NSNull *` instead of `NSString *`, that will take care of compliler complaining that `something == [NSNull null]`

Comment: @Avi on my builds, if the compiler gives a warning it doesn't allow it :-)  (Strict zero warning policy).